# How to determine (via timestamp) whenever a specific field in a table is edited in MS Access?

Tags: database, ms-access

I have a table in MS Access where the email field is updated often. Using Macros, I am able to determine when the entire record is edited. However, I would like to record (with a timestamp) whenever the "EMAIL" field is updated. That is, only when the email field is updated and NOT any other field. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the update is always going to occur via a form, then the simple addition of some code to the after update event of the email text box on the form would suffice.

Eg:

```
Me.LastEmailUpdate = Now()
Me.EmailAddress = Me.Email
```